# Array of structs with Array in the struct

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic-allocation

I am completely stuck on this problem... The code structure that is given is as follows:

```
typedef struct _myvar{
   uint32_t someInt;
   uint32_t *ptr;
} myvar;
...
myvar **var;
..
var = new myvar*[x]; // where x is an int
for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){ // y is usually 2 or 4
   var[i] = new myvar[z]; //create dynamic 2d array
   for(int j = 0; j < z; j++){
      var[i][j].ptr = new int[b]; //where b is another int
   }
}
```

What happens is I want to create a 2d structure that has one part of it being 3d i.e. the ptr is just a pointer to an array of ints.

My code compiles but I get seg faults in trying to allocate memory so ptr can point to it. I tried working on this for about an hour and figure it was time for some help.

Thanks!

EDIT1: Fixed code issue in regards to comment on code not compiling.. Secondly... I cannot use vectors as much as I would like to... The data structure that I have there is what I have to use.

EDIT2: b is dynamic and set at the command line. For testing purposes use 16.

Comment: Use `std::vector` wherever possible because it maintains copies of items and manages dynamic memory allocation so you don't have to.

Comment: That code won't compile. `var = new myvar[z]` will not work on `myvar **var`.

Comment: and have you tried (var[i])[j].ptr?

Comment: just did and I still get a seg fault when trying to access it... so i.e. `cout << myvar[i][j].ptr[k].` where i, j, k should be within the array bounds that were previously used to declare it.

Comment: so whats you problem now - you say 'fixed the code issu'

Comment: Are you sure that `y` in the first for loop will never be greater than `x`?

Comment: I am sure that all variables are within their expected bounds. and the 'fix code issue' was in regards to the comment on code not compiling.

Comment: Also you're initializing an `uint32_t*` with an `int` array. I'd say pick one, `uint32_t` or `int`, but don't mix them.

Comment: Well all of that aside - I am still having the issue of not being able to set ptr[k] to a value. If you had to take this code and then set `myvar[0][0].ptr[0] = 5` how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused with your indices. In your first loop you use var[i], so i must stop at x, not at y. For the columns I have used j and y. Not sure what z is.
Then, as pointed out by others, you shouldn't mix int and uint32_t.
Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct _myvar{
   uint32_t someInt;
   uint32_t *ptr;
} myvar;

int main() {

    myvar **var;

    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;

    var = new myvar*[x]; // where x is an int
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) { // i stops at x
        var[i] = new myvar[y]; //create dynamic 2d array
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
            var[i][j].ptr = new uint32_t[16]; // used 16 for testing
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay so I have exactly what you have here and I still cannot access any part of ptr. i.e. if I want to set `var[0][0].ptr[0] = 0;` (numerical 0 not pntr) I get a seg fault. This is were I am confused...

Comment: @Sharki Could you please post your precise code? I have tried this:
`var[0][0].ptr[0] = 0;
 cout << "var[0][0].ptr[0] is " << var[0][0].ptr[0] << endl;
 var[2][3].ptr[15] = 15;
 cout << "var[2][3].ptr[15] is " << var[2][3].ptr[15] << endl;`
and it works.